# Fixed nav menu with z-index 1000 doesn't cover angular material components

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a fixed navbar that opens up when a user clicks on the hamburger icon. Problem is, it covers all elements in the page except for the elements that are actually Angular material components.

[image: screenshot of website]

As you can see in the picture, get started and token buttons are not covered by the hamburger menu like the rest of the page.

This is my fixed navbar scss:

```
position: fixed;
width: 80vw;
height: 100vh;
z-index: 1000;
transition: 0.23s;
background-color: $snd-dark-lighter;

padding: 0 28px;

top: 0;
right: -100vw;
```

Action buttons html:

```
      <div class="container__action--buttons">
        <button mat-flat-button>
          Get started
          <mat-icon>arrow_forward</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button mat-stroked-button>
          <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
          Sonido token
        </button>
      </div>
```

actions buttons scss:

```
        .container__action--buttons {
            button {
              font-size: 14px;
              font-weight: 400;

              height: 48px;

              &.mat-flat-button {
                background-color: $snd-green;
                margin-right: 25px;
              }

              &.mat-stroked-button {
                border: 1px solid $snd-white;
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: you should check position in parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using z-index and try to put your menu above all the elements on the page you can try using [Angular Material CDK Overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview). By the help of the overlay you can show your menu and overlay will ensure it will be above all the elements rendered on the page.